# Is it a good idea to test an Apple Recovery Key for your Apple computer?

Tags: recovery, apple

Out of the blue my Apple computer would not accept either the password or the recovery key. I ended up having to erase and restore via a backup - great to have backups!  But I was very surprised the recovery key didn't work (It was correct).  My questions:

1. Should I test the recovery key after I restore and re-encrypt the computer? Are there any issues that I should be aware of if I do test it.
2. Assuming a user error didn't occur - why would both a password and a recovery key not work? Some kind of corruption?

Comment: It could have possibly gotten corrupted. I've had that happen before on a laptop when it lost power when the battery died. It's always a good thing to validate the encryption after being applied to make sure it works correctly.

Comment: Great - thanks, I agree! It's taken me a few days to recover from this. I've always validated other types of recover codes  or key, this one I didn't. I think I thought it was a one time use kind of deal.